# Trouble adding a normal curve to histogram in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, histogram, curve

I'm trying to add a normal distribution curve to a histogram using `curve`.
This is my code:

```
hist(df$col, freq=T)
curve( dnorm(x, mean=8.9,sd=5), 0, 30, add=T, col="blue")
```

The histogram does look fine, but the curve is not adequately displayed (just a blue line on the x axis)

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: The issue is a different scaling. The normal distribution is a density so at the mean the "frequency" = 0.3989. That is why the line is flat. Multiply the "dnorm(x, mean=8.9,sd=5)" by your sample size. I think that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `freq = FALSE` in `hist()` works for me. Reproducible example:

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 8.9, sd = 5) # your df$col
mean_x <- mean(x)
sd_x <- sd(x)

hist(x, freq = FALSE) 

curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean_x, sd = sd_x), add = TRUE, col = "blue")
```

Comment: You may have to manually adjust `ylim` after inspecting this plot if the curve is higher than the histogram.